# How to implement such an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to implement an object of type on ts:

```
{
    "validElements": {
        "classNames": [],
        ...: []
    }, 
    "invalidElements": {
        "classNames": [],
        ...: []
    }
}
```

My code and error:

```
interface outputObject {
    "validElements": {
        "classNames": Array
    }, 
    "invalidElements": {
        "classNames": Array
    }
}
```

*The universal type "Array" requires the following number of type arguments: 1.*

**But the bigger question here is how do I then use such an interface to add and remove values from it. In fact, I have an eventlistener where I validate the fields and, depending on the value, add a class to one or another array, and then return the object**

Also, I will need to add values and delete from arrays that are inside the object. I tried to do it through the interface, but I get the error that arguments are required. How to do it more correctly?

Comment: Please provide the exact error you're getting

Comment: interface outputObject {
    "validElements": {
        "classNames": Array
    }, 
    "invalidElements": {
        "classNames": Array
    }
}
 /// 
The universal type "Array<T>" requires the following number of type arguments: 1.
 /// 
But the bigger question here is how do I then use such an interface to add and remove values from it. In fact, I have an eventlistener where I validate the fields and, depending on the value, add a class to one or another array, and then return the object

Comment: @123321: please add this stuff directly to the post, nobody can read it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an object and specific your type to that object and also change your type from `Array` to `Array<string>` as per the first answer.

```
const outputObject: OutputObject = {
 "validElements": {
        "classNames": []
 }, 
 "invalidElements": {
        "classNames": []
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is generic type which requires type arguments. You can do it like this:

```
interface OutputObject {
  validElements: {
    classNames: string[];  
  }
  invalidElements: {
    classNames: string[];  
  }
}
```

Note that `string[]` is shortcut for `Array<string>`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it worked, but the question is, how do I make a call to this interface and work with it to save values? I have a class, constructor and some functions.

`class testPackage {
constructor() {
 // logic
}

someFunction(): OutputObject {
// logic
}
}`
It is not necessary to return this interface, I will need to use it as a json object in the future, but the main thing is to be able to add and remove values. How do I initialize it? I will be very grateful